# How to fix the annotation image on map view?

Tags: ios, dictionary, rotation

I am working on app which will show the current user location on map.I am using the custom annotation on map view for example a car image.I am rotating this image by finding the angle between two locations.But whenever user rotates the map view my annotation also rotates which is for obvious reason and my image moves in wrong direction.In android we can set flat property to true so whenever user will rotate the map the annotation image will also rotate along with it.
          Please suggest something useful.Thank you.

Comment: Yes, for this you need to calculate the angle first. Generally the annotation image set up with the angle 0. So whenever map will rotate it will return you an required angle.You can get this angle using this:' MKMapCamera *camera = self.mapView.camera;
    CLLocationDirection mapAngle = camera.heading;
[MKAnnotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((newAngle)*0.0174532925)] '. It will also rotate the annotation image along with the map.

Comment: Ah thanks for the info. Yeah I came across this solution too but aren't 100% happy with it for two reasons. The tooltip things that pop up when you touch the annotation are also at an angle, and the annotation doesn't rotate while the user is rotating the map, it only snaps to the correct rotation once the user has finished rotating the map. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Hey Kurt. Sorry for late reply."It only snaps to the correct rotation once the user has finished rotating the map." you need to save the previous angle of that annotation and have to use the '-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated'so whenever your map will rotate you need to check those annotation's respective angles. For the second reason:-"The tooltip things that pop up when you touch the annotation are also at an angle", I have searched almost all stack overflow but had not found any solution about that.You can fix the toolTip in the 0 degree angle.